# change control template based on current theme

Tags: wpf, themes, controltemplate

Unfortunately I had to override the control template of one of the `TabControl`s in my application because I needed to do some slight modification on the look and feel that couldn't be done otherwise.

```
<TabControl Name="specialTabControl" Template="{StaticResource SpecialTabControlTemplate} />".
```

All looks fine until I switch the theme of the OS. Now my `TabControl`looks totally rubbish because it uses the control template of the wrong theme (the theme I based my control template on, extracted with Blend).

So I guess need to find a way to provide 4 control templates (luna, aero, xp, classic) for that special `TabControl` that need to be selected according to the current OS theme.

So how can provide and apply **different** custom control templates for `specialTabControl` based on the current theme, so that when the user switches the theme of the OS, that `specialTabControl` will switch to the control template I have provided for that theme?

Please note that I have also other `TabControl`s in the application that do not have an override control template and should always have the standard control template for that theme.

Comment: Each time anyone recommends assigning a new ControlTemplate for solving some problem I stop reading exactly due to this problem, which always immediately pops into my mind.

Comment: You could also write templates for all kind of controls so your application and all its controls will look the same in all themes - no matter what new theme will be there in the future. That's what e.g. Microsoft Office does I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to see the themes in WPF application. Assembly can contains the following lines:

[assembly:ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.**SourceAssembly**,
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]

This means that the system themes of application located in your assembly (in folder /themes). The name of themes must comply with system themes... for example:

```
The Aero theme (Windows Vista and Windows 7): themes\Aero.NormalColor.xaml
The default Windows XP theme: themes\Luna.NormalColor.xaml
The olive green Windows XP theme: themes\Luna.Homestead.xaml
The Windows Classic theme: themes\Classic.xaml
```

When the user changes skin of system, the WPF application will automatically download your themes. Accordingly, you can set control template for each system theme. More information can be found in:

"Adam Nathan. WPF 4 Unleashed". Chapter 14.

Theming WPF Applications:
http://blogs.infosupport.com/theming-wpf-applications/

I hope this helps.

*** EDIT ***

I found an interesting example in which refers to the actually change theme:

http://northhorizon.net/2010/how-to-actually-change-the-system-theme-in-wpf/

You can set the explicit style, which will not respond to changes skin in system:

```
<Style x:Key="ExplicitGreenButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Accordingly, the implicit style will respond to changes system skin:

```
<Style x:Key="ImplicitGreenButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Also, in example contain is a useful code at **ThemeHelper**, wherein some themes functions.

*** EDIT #2 ***

If I understand correctly, first you need to get system theme name. This action can be done in several ways.

The first is to use the Win32-functions from the library "UxTheme.dll" like **GetCurrentThemeName()**:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetCurrentThemeName(StringBuilder pszThemeFileName, int dwMaxNameChars, StringBuilder pszColorBuff, int dwMaxColorChars, StringBuilder pszSizeBuff, int cchMaxSizeChars);

StringBuilder stringThemeName = new StringBuilder(260);
StringBuilder stringColorName = new StringBuilder(260);
StringBuilder stringSizeName = new StringBuilder(260);

Int32 s = GetCurrentThemeName(stringThemeName, 260, stringColorName, 260, stringSizeName, 260);
```

But I have this function does not correctly received some system theme names, such as "Classic". So I tried a different way.

The second way is a get theme name from registry. In path **"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\LastTheme"** contains current system theme. So do we need to intercept a "Change system theme event" via window hook.

Below is an example with few buttons, style which varies depending on the system theme:

Add to window:

```
SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized"
```

Styles:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="CadetBlue" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="LunaStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ClassicStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

Main grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}" Content="Default button" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Button Name="ChangeButtonStyle" Content="Changes style" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <TextBlock Name="CurrentTheme" FontSize="16" Text="Null" Width="150" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

In code:

Intercept a "Change system theme event":

```
private IntPtr hwnd;
private HwndSource hsource;

private void Window_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle) == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not get window handle.");
    }

    hsource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd);
    hsource.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case 0x31A:          // Define this as WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED for Windows 7
        case 0x31E:          // Define this as WM_THEMECHANGED

        // Action on the change system theme
        GetThemeName(SubKey, Value); 

        return IntPtr.Zero;

        default:

        return IntPtr.Zero;
     }
}
```

Get the system theme name and set style:

```
public string SubKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\LastTheme";
public string Value = "ThemeFile";

private void GetThemeName(string OpenKey, string Value)
{
    RegistryKey pRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
    pRegKey = pRegKey.OpenSubKey(OpenKey);
    Object val = pRegKey.GetValue(Value);
    string NameThemeFile = val as string;

    if (NameThemeFile.IndexOf("Luna") != -1)
    {
        ChangeButtonStyle.Style = this.FindResource("LunaStyle") as Style;
        CurrentTheme.Text = "Luna";
    }

    if (NameThemeFile.IndexOf("Classic") != -1)
    {
        ChangeButtonStyle.Style = this.FindResource("ClassicStyle") as Style;
        CurrentTheme.Text = "Classic";
    }
}
```

This method is not the best, but will start.

Comment: but how can I use the default theme (that comes from WPF itself) for one TabControl and a custom theme (that switches based on the current OS theme) for another TabControl?

Comment: Thank you for the updated detailed answer, but I think you have not yet quite understood my problem. I do not want to theme the whole application and I do not want have a fixed theme/style. I would like to provide 4 controltemplates (luna, classic, aero, xp) for ***one*** `TabControl` and it should switch to that control template whenever the OS theme was changed. In the same application there are also  `TabControl`s that do not have a custom control template and just should behave like regular tab controls using the current OS theme's style.

Comment: I have updated my question with a hopefully better explanation.